# Why ping with source address?

Tags: ping

What is the practical use of it?

Just pinging the target from whatever interfaces and then getting the reply can already ensure the target is up. So, why do we have to specify the source IP Address?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

The biggest reason is that the return path from the destination back to you may depend on the source address. Often you want to test the network path in both directions.

Furthermore things like policy routing, ingress filtering, firewalls, NAT etc may behave differently depending on the source address.

Answer (score -1):

Testing network reachability is the purpose behind sourcing a ping off of a specific network.  From a router's CLI, a simple ping uses the interface facing the packet destination as the source address.  An extended ping offers the ability to source the ping from a different connected interface (subnet), for example, the privately addressed LAN side subnet.